# Add line break after 2 database rows PHP

Tags: php, html, database, rows

I am trying to make a page where multiple items are being pulled from a database and showed on the site. I would like to add a line break after every 2 rows that are received from the database so it shows correctly.

I tried alot and did alot of research but it still doesn't work. Anybody got an idea what i'm doing wrong?

```html
<?php
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","article_user","mypassword");

  if (!$con)
  {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

  mysql_select_db("articles", $con);

$query = "SELECT * FROM `Articles`";
$select_projects = mysql_query($query);

$xi=1;


if (mysql_num_rows($select_projects) > 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($select_projects)) {
 echo '<div class="col-md-6 related-post-block">';
 echo '<div class="related-img"> <img src="file-upload/server/php/files/'.$row['image'].'" class="" alt></a> </div>';
        echo '<h3>'.$row['header'].'</a></h3>';
 echo '<p>'.$row['text'].'</p>';
 echo '</div>';
        
       if ($xi % 2 == 0)
           echo '<br />';
       $xi++;
     }

}

mysql_close($db);

?>
```

Comment: What do you mean "it isn't working"?  What output are you getting?

Comment: May be because of `a` tag not opened anywhere , but only closed.  Try after fixing this.

Comment: @dave There is no space between the rows, looks like this: http://prntscr.com/c6uoaz while it should look like http://prntscr.com/c6uova

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need another element to change the appearance, this should be fixed with css.  Probably something like:

```
.related-post-block {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Or if you want to inline it (which I don't recommend):

```
echo '<div class="col-md-6 related-post-block" style="margin-bottom: 15px">';
```

Comment: Wow.... why didn't I think about this. Was to busy finding some sort of php to fix this than just thinking. Thnx!

Answer (score 0):

When you omit the braces it will only treat the next statement as body of the condition.

if ($x)
  echo 'foo';
  echo 'bar';
will always print "bar"

So it will never get to use the `<br />`; Add curly braces to your if statement.

Comment: ...but the next statement is the echo

Answer (score 0):

`br` tag doesn't work after `div` tag, you can try this :

```
if ($xi % 2 == 0)
    echo '<div style="clear:both; margin-bottom:20px"></div>';
$xi++;
```

Comment: Its not about the div, I just want some white space after the paragraph. 
It looks like this: http://prntscr.com/c6uoaz while it should look like http://prntscr.com/c6uova

Comment: just add little margin-bottom, see changes